# Does graphql support non-nullable optional field?

Tags: graphql

I am using graphql as the interface. When design the schema I can't find a way to support non-nullable optional fields. For example:

```
mutation {
  createUser (firstName: String!, lastName: String!, middleName: String): Void
}
```

for above mutation, I'd like to make the `middlename` as optional but also don't accept `null` value. Is it possible to do in graphql?

Answer (score 3):

The graphql spec mentions that non-nullable input fields are always required.

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/main/spec/Section%203%20--%20Type%20System.md#input-objects

Quoting:

> If no value is provided for a defined input object field and that
> field definition provides a default value, the default value should be
> used. If no default value is provided and the input object field's
> type is non-null, an error should be raised. Otherwise, if the field
> is not required, then no entry is added to the coerced unordered map.